# How to convert a hive date into the following format: from 2016-11-28 to 28-Nov-16?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

How to convert a hive date into the following format: from 2016-11-28 to 28-Nov-16 ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I actually found a simpler solution:

```
select date_format(current_date(),'dd-MMM-yy')
```

This accomplished what was needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert your date into a timestamp using the `unix_timestamp` function. You can then format this timestamp using `from_unixtime` function :

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-11-28', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd-MMM-yy')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @cheseaux